# How to output console to html

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I am devolipng an Android Cordova app. While testing app on actual device I canno't access console.
I did intercept `console.log` messages and output them to html with:

```
function report(string){
    $('#log').append(string + '<br>');
}

if(window.console){
    console.oldLog = console.log;
    console.log = function(str){
        console.oldLog(str);
        report('Console: ' + str);
    }
}
```

, but that excludes error messages and every other tipe of message in console.
How can I output all console messages to HTML?

Comment: Take a look at this: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging

Comment: override `console.error`, `console.debug` ... ? Also you don't need to add a property on console as `console.oldLog`, you can create a local scope variable that hold the last value of console.log

Comment: How can I override console.error(). It seems that it needs more atributes than 1, but I can't find how the original function is written.

Comment: Ok, overrode console.error and console.debug. But only errors that show up are the ones I call myself in console.

Answer (score 1):

With the [org.apache.cordova.console](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-console/blob/master/doc/index.md) plugin and the [ADB cli-tool](https://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html#Enabling) you can show the `console.log` output, like:

```
$ adb logcat
```

Wherever, I recomend you use the [Remote debugging of Webviews](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging#debugging-webviews), with Android 4.4+ and Google Chrome (or [Chromium](http://www.chromium.org/)), you can debug your application with the native developers-tools of Chrome (with console, inspector, and everything).

If you are running the emulator, open Chrome and go to `Chrome menu > More tools > Inspect Devices.` or put the url `chrome://inspect` and enable the **Discover USB devices** if you do not see your emulator.

For real Android devices you need to enable the development options, I recomend you [check this guide](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging)